# Angular js - Multiple input per row edit & save

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <table border="1">
        <tr data-ng-repeat="item in items">
            <td data-ng-repeat="textValue in item.value">
               <input type="text" data-ng-model="textValue" data-ng-readonly="isReadonly" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Edit" data-ng-click="enableEdit();" />
</div>
```

Will have multiple rows with multiple input type text for each row. Initially onload input type are set to readonly. Once user press the edit button all of the input box will become editable. User can change the text box values & save the updated values by clicking on save button.

```
var MyModule = angular.module('MyModule', []);

  MyModule.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.isReadonly = true;
    $scope.items = [{
      "id": 1,
      "value": {
        "value1": 10,
        "value2": 20,
        "value3": 30,
        "value4": 40
      }
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "value": {
        "value1": 50,
        "value2": 60,
        "value3": 70,
        "value4": 80
      }
    }];

    $scope.enableEdit = function() {
      $scope.isReadonly = false;
    }

  });
```

Follow the below plnkr url

http://plnkr.co/edit/g0bpUg2AVjNhWAXG8PXc?p=preview

Comment: apologize but I do not see the question here? Your plnkr seems to be working no?

Comment: I don't see the question/problem?

Comment: yes it works. But on click of save how to get the values for each rows input box so that can save the data.

Comment: Ahh! I see, look at the below answer section for more info.

Comment: FYI: You don't have to save the data explicitly as you are already using `ng-model` for that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem you are facing is related to changes not getting reflected back to the model.
The assumption was made because you haven't told us your problem in the first place.

**Note:** I've also added the `saveValues()` function for completeness.
The problem is due to how `ngRepeat` directive works and how you have used it. `ng-repeat` creates a child scope for each `textValue` and in these child scopes, `ng-repeat` does not create a 2-way binding for the `textValue` value. And so your model was never updated.

There are two different ways to solve this: 

P.S: Example#2 is just for the demonstration of `object` technique and should be avoided for your use-case as it would further complicate the data structure of `items`.

Example#1) Using `(key, value)` like:

```js
  var MyModule = angular.module('MyModule', []);

  MyModule.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.isReadonly = true;
    $scope.items = [{
      "id": 1,
      "value": {
        "value1": 10,
        "value2": 20,
        "value3": 30,
        "value4": 40
      }
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "value": {
        "value1": 50,
        "value2": 60,
        "value3": 70,
        "value4": 80
      }
    }];

    $scope.enableEdit = function() {
      $scope.isReadonly = false;
    }
    $scope.saveValues = function() {
      $scope.isReadonly = true;
      console.log($scope.items)
    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="MyModule">
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <table border="1">
    <tr data-ng-repeat="item in items">
      <td data-ng-repeat="(key, textValue) in item.value">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="item.value[key]" data-ng-readonly="isReadonly" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" value="Edit" data-ng-click="enableEdit();" />
  <input type="button" value="Save" data-ng-click="saveValues();" />
</div>
```

Example#2) Using `objects` like:

```js
var MyModule = angular.module('MyModule', []);

MyModule.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
  $scope.isReadonly = true;
  $scope.items = [{
    "id": 1,
    "value": {
      "value1": {
        "value": 10
      },
      "value2": {
        "value": 20
      },
      "value3": {
        "value": 30
      },
      "value4": {
        "value": 40
      }
    }
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "value": {
      "value1": {
        "value": 50
      },
      "value2": {
        "value": 60
      },
      "value3": {
        "value": 70
      },
      "value4": {
        "value": 80
      }
    }
  }];

  $scope.enableEdit = function() {
    $scope.isReadonly = false;
  }
  $scope.saveValues = function() {
    $scope.isReadonly = true;
    console.log($scope.items)
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="MyModule">
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <table border="1">
    <tr data-ng-repeat="item in items">
      <td data-ng-repeat="textValue in item.value">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="textValue.value" data-ng-readonly="isReadonly" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" value="Edit" data-ng-click="enableEdit();" />
  <input type="button" value="Save" data-ng-click="saveValues();" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using ng-if to toggle between the controls as below

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in items">
            <td data-ng-repeat="textValue in item.value">
              <label class="form-control" ng-if="isReadonly">{{textValue}} </label>
              <input type="text" ng-if="!isReadonly" data-ng-model="textValue" />
            </td>
          </tr>
```

Controller Method

```
 $scope.enableEdit = function() {
      $scope.isReadonly = false;
    }
    $scope.saveValues=function(){

       $scope.isReadonly = true;
    }
```

**[LIVE DEMO(UPDATED PLUNK)](http://plnkr.co/edit/NHxd53T1ja4I4C2TD2ge?p=preview)**